# Best practice to loop through an array of Functions with different signatures in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have an array of javascript functions `Functs = [f1, f2, f3...]` and I want to loop over the array, executing each function in sequence.

**Edit:** Currently, we do have the functions called explicitly in the loop `while(true){f1(a,b,c); f2(b); f3(c)...}`. However, we would like to make this pipeline extendable so users can insert custom functions into the pipeline at any stage by providing a public method for inserting items into the array, resulting in: `while(true){f1(a,b,c); f2(b); fCustom(b,c); f3(c)...}`. So, an externally-editable pipeline. Maybe there is a better way to do this, but an editable array of functions seemed the most straightforward way.

The problem is, each function has a different signature and requires different inputs like so:

```
f1 = function(name, address, date) {};
f2 = function(name, age) {};
f3 = function(height);
```

And the functions would be looped over like so:

```
mainFunction() {

  let name = something;
  let address = something;
  let date = something;
  ....
  let height = something;

  while(condition == true) {
    for(f in Functs) {
      f(?????); //Each f() has a different signature?
    } 
  }
}
```

How do I ensure I can pass the required parameters to each function? I was thinking something like this with a parameters object and wrapping the functions inside, but don't know how clean that would be. At least the functions could keep their unique signatures, but this still seems like a kludge.

**Edit:** Given the list of values (name, age, date, etc.), each function is processing this block of data in a sequential pipeline. Maybe one function checks the `age` value and if it meets a certain condition, modify `date`. The next function will look at the `name` and `date` functions and manipulate them some way, then overwrite `name` with the result. Until one stage in the pipeline (perhaps after several loops) detects that everything has been fully processed. So each stage needs to be able to mutate these parameters so that the changes are visible to the next function in the sequence, i.e.:`f2 = function(height) {height += 2;}` `f3 = function(name, age, height){if(height > age) condition = false;}`

```
mainFunction() {
  let params = {
    name : something,
    address : something,
    date : something,
    ...
    height : something
  };

  f1 = function(params) {
    f1Inner = function (params.name, params.address, params.date) {};
  }

  Functs = [f1, f2, f3...]

  while(condition == true) {
    for(f in Functs) {
      f(params);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Where and how do you get the parameters for each function?

Comment: Do you know you can use the arguments (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) special variable in a function and don't even use the signature?

Comment: You can use destructuring. `f1 = function({name, address, date}) {}` and so on.

Comment: No `f2 = (height) {height += 2;}` will not modify anything outside the function. Can you share more details about what you're actually trying to do? It seems a bit like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346503/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-xy-problem).

Comment: "*each function has a different signature and requires different inputs*" - then the best practice is **not to put them in the same array** together at all.

Comment: Can you add a proper example of what the functions will do and will return? At least for 2 functions. `f2 = (height) {height += 2;}` doesn't do anything. It just increments the parameter

Comment: @VLAZ This is for processing a large block of data in a pipeline following a sequence of steps. Each function provides a particular step of the pipeline, and currently, we do have the functions called explicitly in the loop `while(true){f1(a,b,c); f2(b); f3(c)...}`. However, we would like to make this pipeline extendable so users can insert custom functions into the pipeline at any stage by providing a public method for inserting items into the array, resulting in: `while(true){f1(a,b,c); f2(b); fCustom(b,c); f3(c)...}`. I hope that clarifies for you.

Comment: @adiga See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing and benchmarking, the fastest method we've come up with is this (using @certainPerformance 's solution as a starting point):

1. Store functions in an array of objects. This allows a user to insert new custom functions anywhere in the list (insert before 'taskA', etc.) and is *much* faster than an object of objects or Map.
2. Call the tasks using `array.some()`. Somewhat faster than `for of` or `for in`, and even seemed slightly faster than `array.map`.
3. Use `function.call()` to call the functions. This allows use of the `this` variable if you need to access other class features, for example. If you do this, you should also pass in `this` to `array.some()`, which preserves the `this` context without needing `bind(this)` which seemed quite slow.
4. For parameters used by only a few functions, use an object `params` which gives a common function signature while allowing custom functions access to any relevant variables. For parameters common to all functions, pass in directly (for speed, especially if modifying that value).

```
//=== List of Pipeline Steps ===//
this.pipelineTasks = [
      { name: 'taskA', func: this.taskA },
      { name: 'taskB', func: this.taskB },
      { name: 'taskC', func: this.taskC }
    ];

// TaskA
TaskA(src, params) {
  return src + params.title;
}

// TaskB
TaskB(src, params) {
  return params.name ? params.name : params.name + "chicken";
}

// TaskC
TaskC(src, params) {
  params.age = params.age + params.shoeSize;
  return params.age > params.shoeSize ? params.age : params.shoeSize;
}

//=== Execute the processing pipeline ===//
processPipeline(src, name, age, shoeSize, title) {
  const myParams = {
    name     : name,
    age      : 10,
    shoeSize : 20,
    title    : title
  };

  while (myParams.age < 100) {
    this.pipelineTasks.some(function(fn) {
      return result = fn.func.call(this, src, myParams);
    }, this));
    
    //Alternatively, with arrow functions
    //  (slightly slower in Chrome, significantly slower in Node with hundreds
    //  of function calls, but doesn't require 'this' in array.some )
    // this.pipelineTasks.some((fn) => result = fn.func.call(this, src, myParams));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd change the functions to accept a single argument as an object, which gets destructured, so that all functions can be called with the same argument:

```
mainFunction() {
  let name = something;
  let address = something;
  let date = something;
  ....
  let height = something;
  const paramsObj = { name, address, date, height };
  for (const fn of Functs) {
    fn(paramsObj);
    // do whatever you need to do with the return value or loop logic
  }
```

and

```
f1 = function({ name, address, date }) {};
f2 = function({ name, age }) {};
f3 = function({ height });
```

If you need these parameters be modified while being passed along as well, you can destructure on the first line instead, allowing you to mutate the params object, eg:

```
f1 = function(params) {
  const { name, address, date } = params;
  if (someCondition) {
    params.height += 2;
  }
};
```

and then subsequent calls will see the changed parameter.

Comment: OP just made an edit that seems to invalidate this approach. I think we need more information here.

Comment: This is still valid if OP uses lodash.cloneDeep (if nested) or Object.assign (if shallow) before passing the options object to the function. JSON.decode(JSON.stringify(options)) would work instead of lodash if all the options are simple objects, arrays or primitives.

Comment: @CharlesBamford I think OP wants to keep the previous values when they execute the next function. So, object mutation is required.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const if_then = (if_fn, then_fn) => (params_object) =>
  if_fn(params_object) ? then_fn(params_object) : null;

const apply_params = (fn, arg_keys, write_to_key = false) => (params_object) => {
  const result = fn(...arg_keys.map((v) => params_object[v]));
  if(write_to_key)
    params_object[write_to_key] = result;
  return result;
};

const name_and_age = (name, age) => name + ' is ' + age + ' and a half years old';
const volume = (height, width, depth) => height * width * depth;
const double_height = (height) => height * 2;
const double_width = (width) => width * 2;

const count_loop = (params_object) => Object.assign(params_object, { loop_count: (params_object.loop_count ?? 0) + 1 })

let functs = [
  count_loop,
  apply_params(double_height, ['height'], 'height'),
  if_then(
    (p) => !p.name_and_age,
    apply_params(name_and_age, ['name', 'age'], 'name_and_age'),
  ),
];

const bob = true;
if(bob)
  functs.push(
    if_then(
      (p) => p.loop_count > 2,
      apply_params(double_width, ['width'], 'width'),
    )
  );

functs = functs.concat([
  apply_params(volume, ['height', 'width', 'depth'], 'volume'),
  console.log
]);

let params = {
  name : 'Orbold the Grim',
  age : 145,
  height: 2,
  width: 0.3,
  depth: 0.2,
};

const should_exit_loop = (params_object) =>
  (params_object.loop_count || 0) > 10 || params_object.height > 8;

while(!should_exit_loop(params)) {
  functs.forEach(
    (f) => f(params)
  );
};
```

Comment: Clever, but at this point, why not just call the functions individually?

Comment: You can probably replace the reduce with `params_list.map(p => params_object[p])`

Comment: @adiga oh yeah ... thanks, I've updated it.